# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Mi Yodeya breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  7         13
Users destroyed                                 103          0
Users deleted                                   113          0
Users contacted                                  11          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            57      1,481
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               11      1,189
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          6      1,393
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                2        364
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 1        752
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               13      2,526
Tags merged                                      17          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            11          7
Tag synonyms created                             11          3
Questions unprotected                             2          0
Questions reopened                               92         53
Questions protected                              14         32
Questions migrated                                5          0
Questions merged                                 10          0
Questions flagged⁴                               44        419
Questions closed                                711        267
Question flags handled⁴                         273        190
Posts unlocked                                    4          5
Posts undeleted                                  35         75
Posts locked                                     14        177
Posts deleted⁵                                  455      1,171
Posts bumped                                      0      2,504
Escalations to the CM team                        8          0
Comments undeleted                              205          0
Comments flagged                                232      2,006
Comments deleted⁶                            11,327      3,618
Comment flags handled                         1,459        779
Bounties canceled                                 1          0
Answers flagged                                 210      1,456
Answer flags handled                            778        888
All comments on a post moved to chat             49          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Thanks for keeping us in the loop! I want to take this opportunity to acknowledge not only our fantastic moderators, but the entire MY community for making Mi Yodeya what it is today, and keeping it clean and tidy!

Comment: How much does the Purim Torah effect the closed questions count?

Comment: You can calculate this, @Mike: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpurim-torah-in-jest%5D+created%3A2018-1-1..2018-12-31+closed%3A1